# Clickhouse server cpu and memory keep growing even when there is no query running

Tags: clickhouse

I am facing a problem that the cpu and memory usage of clickhouse server process keep growing even when there is no query running. The memory useage keeps growing the to the max usage in config.xml, and then drops to a low level, growing to the limit, and then drops again, periodcally. I am using clickhouse 22.4.2.1.

I am wondering if it is related to the background mutations or merges, but I can not found more details about it.

Here is the error log:

```
2023.03.16 09:12:38.923620 [ 29052 ] {} <Error> void DB::MergeTreeBackgroundExecutor<DB::MergeMutateRuntimeQueue>::routine(DB::TaskRuntimeDataPtr) [Queue = DB::MergeMutateRuntimeQueue]: Code: 241. DB::Exception: Memory limit (total) exceeded: would use 12.90 GiB (attempt to allocate chunk of 4298894320 bytes), maximum: 11.18 GiB: While executing ReplacingSorted. (MEMORY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):

0. DB::Exception::Exception(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, bool) @ 0xb6fa67a in /usr/bin/clickhouse
1. DB::Exception::Exception<char const*, char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, long&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >(int, fmt::v8::basic_format_string<char, fmt::v8::type_identity<char const*>::type, fmt::v8::type_identity<char const*>::type, fmt::v8::type_identity<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::type, fmt::v8::type_identity<long&>::type, fmt::v8::type_identity<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::type>, char const*&&, char const*&&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&&, long&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&&) @ 0xb712703 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
2. MemoryTracker::allocImpl(long, bool, MemoryTracker*) @ 0xb712430 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
3. MemoryTracker::allocImpl(long, bool, MemoryTracker*) @ 0xb711e77 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
4. MemoryTracker::allocImpl(long, bool, MemoryTracker*) @ 0xb711e77 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
5. Allocator<false, false>::realloc(void*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long) @ 0xb51115b in /usr/bin/clickhouse
6. DB::ColumnString::insertFrom(DB::IColumn const&, unsigned long) @ 0x165494a1 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
7. DB::ReplacingSortedAlgorithm::insertRow() @ 0x172a8e1f in /usr/bin/clickhouse
8. DB::ReplacingSortedAlgorithm::merge() @ 0x172a9066 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
9. DB::IMergingTransform<DB::ReplacingSortedAlgorithm>::work() @ 0x169f8a71 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
10. DB::ExecutionThreadContext::executeTask() @ 0x17051528 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
11. DB::PipelineExecutor::executeStepImpl(unsigned long, std::__1::atomic<bool>*) @ 0x17044b9e in /usr/bin/clickhouse
12. DB::PipelineExecutor::executeStep(std::__1::atomic<bool>*) @ 0x170443a0 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
13. DB::PullingPipelineExecutor::pull(DB::Chunk&) @ 0x1705610e in /usr/bin/clickhouse
14. DB::PullingPipelineExecutor::pull(DB::Block&) @ 0x1705646c in /usr/bin/clickhouse
15. DB::MergeTask::ExecuteAndFinalizeHorizontalPart::executeImpl() @ 0x169e88ab in /usr/bin/clickhouse
16. DB::MergeTask::ExecuteAndFinalizeHorizontalPart::execute() @ 0x169e880b in /usr/bin/clickhouse
17. DB::MergeTask::execute() @ 0x169ee1fa in /usr/bin/clickhouse
18. DB::MergePlainMergeTreeTask::executeStep() @ 0x169ddb8c in /usr/bin/clickhouse
19. DB::MergeTreeBackgroundExecutor<DB::MergeMutateRuntimeQueue>::routine(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::TaskRuntimeData>) @ 0xb6d1045 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
20. DB::MergeTreeBackgroundExecutor<DB::MergeMutateRuntimeQueue>::threadFunction() @ 0xb6d0a8e in /usr/bin/clickhouse
21. ThreadPoolImpl<ThreadFromGlobalPool>::worker(std::__1::__list_iterator<ThreadFromGlobalPool, void*>) @ 0xb7a8afa in /usr/bin/clickhouse
22. ThreadFromGlobalPool::ThreadFromGlobalPool<void ThreadPoolImpl<ThreadFromGlobalPool>::scheduleImpl<void>(std::__1::function<void ()>, int, std::__1::optional<unsigned long>)::'lambda0'()>(void&&)::'lambda'()::operator()() @ 0xb7aaae4 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
23. ThreadPoolImpl<std::__1::thread>::worker(std::__1::__list_iterator<std::__1::thread, void*>) @ 0xb7a5f27 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
24. ? @ 0xb7a995d in /usr/bin/clickhouse
25. start_thread @ 0x7ea5 in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
26. clone @ 0xfeb0d in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
 (version 22.4.2.1 (official build))
2023.03.16 09:13:14.605532 [ 29054 ] {045ff1da-96e3-4dbb-b2c7-d475dc7354f0::1a853d5a8b5ba946ae95784034552dfc_671166_672754_4_684450} <Error> MutatePlainMergeTreeTask: Code: 241. DB::Exception: Memory limit (total) exceeded: would use 12.93 GiB (attempt to allocate chunk of 4260928 bytes), maximum: 11.18 GiB: (while reading column device_id): (while reading from part /var/lib/clickhouse/store/045/045ff1da-96e3-4dbb-b2c7-d475dc7354f0/1a853d5a8b5ba946ae95784034552dfc_671166_672754_4_673027/ from mark 0 with max_rows_to_read = 8192): While executing MergeTreeInOrder. (MEMORY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED) (version 22.4.2.1 (official build))
2023.03.16 09:13:14.658441 [ 29054 ] {045ff1da-96e3-4dbb-b2c7-d475dc7354f0::1a853d5a8b5ba946ae95784034552dfc_671166_672754_4_684450} <Error> virtual bool DB::MutatePlainMergeTreeTask::executeStep(): Code: 241. DB::Exception: Memory limit (total) exceeded: would use 12.93 GiB (attempt to allocate chunk of 4260928 bytes), maximum: 11.18 GiB: (while reading column device_id): (while reading from part /var/lib/clickhouse/store/045/045ff1da-96e3-4dbb-b2c7-d475dc7354f0/1a853d5a8b5ba946ae95784034552dfc_671166_672754_4_673027/ from mark 0 with max_rows_to_read = 8192): While executing MergeTreeInOrder. (MEMORY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):

0. DB::Exception::Exception(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, bool) @ 0xb6fa67a in /usr/bin/clickhouse
1. DB::Exception::Exception<char const*, char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, long&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >(int, fmt::v8::basic_format_string<char, fmt::v8::type_identity<char const*>::type, fmt::v8::type_identity<char const*>::type, fmt::v8::type_identity<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::type, fmt::v8::type_identity<long&>::type, fmt::v8::type_identity<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::type>, char const*&&, char const*&&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&&, long&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&&) @ 0xb712703 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
2. MemoryTracker::allocImpl(long, bool, MemoryTracker*) @ 0xb712430 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
3. MemoryTracker::allocImpl(long, bool, MemoryTracker*) @ 0xb711e77 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
4. MemoryTracker::allocImpl(long, bool, MemoryTracker*) @ 0xb711e77 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
5. void DB::PODArrayBase<8ul, 4096ul, Allocator<false, false>, 15ul, 16ul>::alloc<>(unsigned long) @ 0xb764780 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
6. DB::SerializationString::deserializeBinaryBulk(DB::IColumn&, DB::ReadBuffer&, unsigned long, double) const @ 0x158c4a8d in /usr/bin/clickhouse
7. DB::ISerialization::deserializeBinaryBulkWithMultipleStreams(COW<DB::IColumn>::immutable_ptr<DB::IColumn>&, unsigned long, DB::ISerialization::DeserializeBinaryBulkSettings&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::ISerialization::DeserializeBinaryBulkState>&, std::__1::unordered_map<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, COW<DB::IColumn>::immutable_ptr<DB::IColumn>, std::__1::hash<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::equal_to<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const, COW<DB::IColumn>::immutable_ptr<DB::IColumn> > > >*) const @ 0x1587bb95 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
8. DB::MergeTreeReaderWide::readData(DB::NameAndTypePair const&, COW<DB::IColumn>::immutable_ptr<DB::IColumn>&, unsigned long, bool, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::__1::unordered_map<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, COW<DB::IColumn>::immutable_ptr<DB::IColumn>, std::__1::hash<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::equal_to<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const, COW<DB::IColumn>::immutable_ptr<DB::IColumn> > > >&, bool) @ 0x16b4ed8f in /usr/bin/clickhouse
9. DB::MergeTreeReaderWide::readRows(unsigned long, unsigned long, bool, unsigned long, std::__1::vector<COW<DB::IColumn>::immutable_ptr<DB::IColumn>, std::__1::allocator<COW<DB::IColumn>::immutable_ptr<DB::IColumn> > >&) @ 0x16b4dd0b in /usr/bin/clickhouse
10. DB::MergeTreeRangeReader::DelayedStream::finalize(std::__1::vector<COW<DB::IColumn>::immutable_ptr<DB::IColumn>, std::__1::allocator<COW<DB::IColumn>::immutable_ptr<DB::IColumn> > >&) @ 0x17326a6e in /usr/bin/clickhouse
11. DB::MergeTreeRangeReader::startReadingChain(unsigned long, std::__1::deque<DB::MarkRange, std::__1::allocator<DB::MarkRange> >&) @ 0x1732b511 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
12. DB::MergeTreeRangeReader::read(unsigned long, std::__1::deque<DB::MarkRange, std::__1::allocator<DB::MarkRange> >&) @ 0x17329cf5 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
13. DB::MergeTreeBaseSelectProcessor::readFromPartImpl() @ 0x1731f4c0 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
14. DB::MergeTreeBaseSelectProcessor::readFromPart() @ 0x173202ed in /usr/bin/clickhouse
15. DB::MergeTreeBaseSelectProcessor::generate() @ 0x1731ea80 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
16. DB::ISource::tryGenerate() @ 0x17031115 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
17. DB::ISource::work() @ 0x17030dba in /usr/bin/clickhouse
18. DB::SourceWithProgress::work() @ 0x17287b42 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
19. DB::ExecutionThreadContext::executeTask() @ 0x17051528 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
20. DB::PipelineExecutor::executeStepImpl(unsigned long, std::__1::atomic<bool>*) @ 0x17044b9e in /usr/bin/clickhouse
21. DB::PipelineExecutor::executeStep(std::__1::atomic<bool>*) @ 0x170443a0 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
22. DB::PullingPipelineExecutor::pull(DB::Chunk&) @ 0x1705610e in /usr/bin/clickhouse
23. DB::PullingPipelineExecutor::pull(DB::Block&) @ 0x1705646c in /usr/bin/clickhouse
24. DB::PartMergerWriter::mutateOriginalPartAndPrepareProjections() @ 0x16ba1d05 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
25. DB::PartMergerWriter::execute() @ 0x16bb4355 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
26. DB::MutateAllPartColumnsTask::executeStep() @ 0x16bb25dc in /usr/bin/clickhouse
27. DB::MutatePlainMergeTreeTask::executeStep() @ 0x16b9e678 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
28. DB::MergeTreeBackgroundExecutor<DB::MergeMutateRuntimeQueue>::routine(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::TaskRuntimeData>) @ 0xb6d1045 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
29. DB::MergeTreeBackgroundExecutor<DB::MergeMutateRuntimeQueue>::threadFunction() @ 0xb6d0a8e in /usr/bin/clickhouse
30. ThreadPoolImpl<ThreadFromGlobalPool>::worker(std::__1::__list_iterator<ThreadFromGlobalPool, void*>) @ 0xb7a8afa in /usr/bin/clickhouse
31. ThreadFromGlobalPool::ThreadFromGlobalPool<void ThreadPoolImpl<ThreadFromGlobalPool>::scheduleImpl<void>(std::__1::function<void ()>, int, std::__1::optional<unsigned long>)::'lambda0'()>(void&&)::'lambda'()::operator()() @ 0xb7aaae4 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
 (version 22.4.2.1 (official build))
2023.03.16 09:13:15.892285 [ 29040 ] {} <Error> void DB::MergeTreeBackgroundExecutor<DB::MergeMutateRuntimeQueue>::routine(DB::TaskRuntimeDataPtr) [Queue = DB::MergeMutateRuntimeQueue]: Code: 241. DB::Exception: Memory limit (total) exceeded: would use 12.93 GiB (attempt to allocate chunk of 4298894320 bytes), maximum: 11.18 GiB: While executing ReplacingSorted. (MEMORY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):

0. DB::Exception::Exception(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, bool) @ 0xb6fa67a in /usr/bin/clickhouse
1. DB::Exception::Exception<char const*, char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, long&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >(int, fmt::v8::basic_format_string<char, fmt::v8::type_identity<char const*>::type, fmt::v8::type_identity<char const*>::type, fmt::v8::type_identity<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::type, fmt::v8::type_identity<long&>::type, fmt::v8::type_identity<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::type>, char const*&&, char const*&&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&&, long&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&&) @ 0xb712703 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
2. MemoryTracker::allocImpl(long, bool, MemoryTracker*) @ 0xb712430 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
3. MemoryTracker::allocImpl(long, bool, MemoryTracker*) @ 0xb711e77 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
4. MemoryTracker::allocImpl(long, bool, MemoryTracker*) @ 0xb711e77 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
5. Allocator<false, false>::realloc(void*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long) @ 0xb51115b in /usr/bin/clickhouse
6. DB::ColumnString::insertFrom(DB::IColumn const&, unsigned long) @ 0x165494a1 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
7. DB::ReplacingSortedAlgorithm::insertRow() @ 0x172a8e1f in /usr/bin/clickhouse
8. DB::ReplacingSortedAlgorithm::merge() @ 0x172a9066 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
9. DB::IMergingTransform<DB::ReplacingSortedAlgorithm>::work() @ 0x169f8a71 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
10. DB::ExecutionThreadContext::executeTask() @ 0x17051528 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
11. DB::PipelineExecutor::executeStepImpl(unsigned long, std::__1::atomic<bool>*) @ 0x17044b9e in /usr/bin/clickhouse
12. DB::PipelineExecutor::executeStep(std::__1::atomic<bool>*) @ 0x170443a0 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
13. DB::PullingPipelineExecutor::pull(DB::Chunk&) @ 0x1705610e in /usr/bin/clickhouse
14. DB::PullingPipelineExecutor::pull(DB::Block&) @ 0x1705646c in /usr/bin/clickhouse
15. DB::MergeTask::ExecuteAndFinalizeHorizontalPart::executeImpl() @ 0x169e88ab in /usr/bin/clickhouse
16. DB::MergeTask::ExecuteAndFinalizeHorizontalPart::execute() @ 0x169e880b in /usr/bin/clickhouse
17. DB::MergeTask::execute() @ 0x169ee1fa in /usr/bin/clickhouse
18. DB::MergePlainMergeTreeTask::executeStep() @ 0x169ddb8c in /usr/bin/clickhouse
19. DB::MergeTreeBackgroundExecutor<DB::MergeMutateRuntimeQueue>::routine(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::TaskRuntimeData>) @ 0xb6d1045 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
20. DB::MergeTreeBackgroundExecutor<DB::MergeMutateRuntimeQueue>::threadFunction() @ 0xb6d0a8e in /usr/bin/clickhouse
21. ThreadPoolImpl<ThreadFromGlobalPool>::worker(std::__1::__list_iterator<ThreadFromGlobalPool, void*>) @ 0xb7a8afa in /usr/bin/clickhouse
22. ThreadFromGlobalPool::ThreadFromGlobalPool<void ThreadPoolImpl<ThreadFromGlobalPool>::scheduleImpl<void>(std::__1::function<void ()>, int, std::__1::optional<unsigned long>)::'lambda0'()>(void&&)::'lambda'()::operator()() @ 0xb7aaae4 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
23. ThreadPoolImpl<std::__1::thread>::worker(std::__1::__list_iterator<std::__1::thread, void*>) @ 0xb7a5f27 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
24. ? @ 0xb7a995d in /usr/bin/clickhouse
25. start_thread @ 0x7ea5 in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
26. clone @ 0xfeb0d in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
 (version 22.4.2.1 (official build))
```

I have tried to upgrade or degrade but nothing helps.

I look into the iftop log and find that there is massive reading rate from s3. Since I have a plenty of tables using s3 storages. Does Clickhouse have some threads running with s3 in the backend?

Comment: how much RAM do you have?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the metrics that Clickhouse expose to see why your memory is kept growing here is the docs that going to help you.

```
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/system-tables/metrics#system_tables-metrics
```